# Finding the Solution to a PDE in the sense of dsitributions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory

I am asked to solve a PDE in the sense of distributions, but I'm kinda confused by the definition. So I am trying to solve the PDE:
$$au_x+bu_y=0$$
Now, let us define $f(bx-ay) = u(x,y)$, where $f$ is only locally integrable. I'm supposed to show that $u(x,y)$ solves this PDE in the sense of distributions. The hint is to make a change of variable so the characteristic directions are the coordinate axes.

Now, I began to solve it:
$$\left< au_x+bu_y ,\phi \right> = \iint_{\mathbb R^2} -u(a\phi_x+b\phi_y) dx dy$$
Where $\phi\in C^{\infty}_c (\mathbb R^2)$. But how do I proceed from here? I'm kinda confused by what the question is asking.

Comment: Replace $u(x,y)$ with $f(bx-ay)$ and make a variable change to $\xi=bx-ay$ and $\eta=ax+by$.

Comment: How do you go about solving this PDE with that change in the sense of distributions? I understand it changes the PDE to $2ab u_{\eta}=0$, and integrating you will get the desired result, but I have done nothing in the sense of distributions. How does this come into play?

Comment: What exactly is the goal of the exercise? Is it to find a general solution or to show that $(x,y) \mapsto f(bx-ay)$ solves the PDE in the sense of distributions?

Comment: It is to show that $u(x,y)=f(bx-ay)$ solves the PDE in the sense of distributions.

Comment: And $f$ is a function, so $\iint f(bx-ay) \, (a\phi_x + b\phi_y) \, dx \, dy$ is defined, and so is a variable change. Distributions might not come into play here, but "in the sense of distribution" does, since we are dealing with a weak solution. However, if it works for a locally integrable function $f$, then we can transfer the situation to $f$ being a distribution.

Comment: So all I have to show is that the solution to the PDE with a change of variables is $f(bx-ay)$? and since $f$ is a locally integrable function, we can say that $f$ is a solution in the sense of distributions?

Comment: According to what you wrote above you shall *not* show that *the* solution to the PDE is $f(bx-ay)$ but that $f(bx-ay)$ is *a* solution to the PDE in the sense of distributions, i.e. that
$$\iint_{\mathbb R^2} f(bx-ay) \, (a\phi_x+b\phi_y) \, dx \, dy = 0.$$

Comment: How can I show this?

Comment: Try the variable change I gave you earlier.

Comment: Well we have the variable change gives:$$\iint_{\mathbb R^2}f(\xi) 2ab \phi_{\eta}$$

Comment: Notice that the integral can now be written
$$2ab \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(\xi) \left( \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \phi_\eta(\xi,\eta) \, d\eta \right) \, d\xi$$
What happens when you do the $\eta$ integral?

Comment: Ah I see, it would yield zero as $\phi$ is a test function

Comment: Now you got it!

Comment: Thank you very much @mdperpe!

Comment: @md2perpe would the term outside the integral only be $2ab$? Don't we need to account for $dx, dy$ so wouldn't there be other factors coming out of those?

Comment: You are right. There will also be a factor $1/(a^2+b^2)$ because of the coordinate change from $dx \, dy$ to $d\xi \, d\eta.$